# Walk directories and create pdf from images

Tags: python, python-os

I have a folder Alpha which contains a series of folders named Beta1, Beta2, ..., Beta 397. Each of the Beta folders contains a variable number of alphanumerically numbered images of different file formats.

My goal is to run a script that crawls all these Beta folders, selectively chooses images of jpeg/png format, and merges them to a pdf (per Beta folder) after name-sort.

My code is stored alongside the Beta folders and reads:-

```
import glob
import re
import img2pdf
import os

_nsre = re.compile('([0-9]+)')
def natural_sort_key(s):
    return [int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
            for text in re.split(_nsre, s)]
            
for X in range(1, 397):
   dirname = os.path.join('./','BetaX', '')
   output  = os.path.join('./','BetaX', '/output.pdf')

   # Get all the filenames per image format
   filenames1 = [f for f in glob.iglob(f'{dirname}*.jpg')]
   filenames2 = [f for f in glob.iglob(f'{dirname}*.png')]
   # Merges the 2 lists
   filenames3 = filenames1 + filenames2 
   # Sort the list alphanumerically
   filenames3.sort(key=natural_sort_key)
   # Print to pdf
   with open(output,"wb") as f:
       f.write(img2pdf.convert(filenames3))
   print(f'Finished converting {output}')
   filenames1.clear()
   filenames2.clear()
   filenames3.clear()
```

If I remove the for loop line and type the value of X, the pdf is outputted without any fuss, on an individual-folder basis. However, I am looking for ways to treat X as a loop-variable from the range and batch-process all the folders at once.

Comment: @Steve `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str` It needs to be `dirname = os.path.join('./','Beta' + str(X), '')`

Comment: Good point.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is currently:

```
for X in range(1, 397):
    dirname = os.path.join('./','BetaX', '')
    output  = os.path.join('./','BetaX', '/output.pdf')
```

The `X` is just a character in the string `BetaX`.  You need to cause `X` to be treated like an integer value and then you need to concatenate that value onto `Beta` to come up with your full folder name.

Also, you don't want the slashes in what you're passing to `os.path.join`.  The point of the `join` call is to hide the details of the path separator character.  The value of `output` will be just `/output.pdf` with what you have, as the third parameter will be considered an absolute path because of the slash at the front of it.

Here's that part of your code with both of these issues addressed:

```
for X in range(1, 397):
    dirname = os.path.join('.','Beta' + str(X), '')
    output  = os.path.join('.','Beta' + str(X), 'output.pdf')
```